# Regex to extract data before and after dot symbols?

Tags: java, regex

I have the un proper data in this way. I need to extract the data before dot and after dot symbol using regular expression.

I am using a Regular expression, but I am not able to get exact data.

I have 2 scenrios:

1. With double Quotes before and after .
2. Without double quotes before and after dot and sometimes before and after there will be no double quotes

---

```
String tableHeading=null;

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\"(.*?)\".*?)\\.(\"(.*?)\".*?)").matcher(formulaData);

    while (matcher.find()) 
    {
    String Column_Data=matcher.group(0);
    String[] pieces = Column_Data.split("\\.");
    tableHeading=pieces[0];
    columnHeading=pieces[1];
     System.out.println(tableHeading+ ": "+columnHeading);
     }//while
```

Comment: can you post an input sample?

Comment: Input is formulaData String variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your regular expression to:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\"([^()]*?)\")\\.(\"?([$\\w ]*)\"?)").matcher(formulaData);
```

`(` and `)` are not expected.

Comment: Hi Sid, For the first FormualData this Expression is valid and parallely i need to handle second version where double quotes are not there see the formuladata which i commented in code. that way also i need to handle. Sample inputdata //String formulaData="FILTER(\"Fact - Bookings\".\"$ Total Gross Bookings\" USING (\"Booking Date\".Quarter =  VALUEOF(\"CUR_QTR\")))";

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `string.split` function just `Matcher` and `Pattern` classes would be enough.

```
String formulaData="(100*(FILTER(\"Fact - Bookings\".\"$ Total Gross Bookings\" USING (\"Booking Date\".\"Year\" =  VALUEOF(\"CUR_YEAR\")))  - FILTER(\"Fact - Bookings\".\"$ Total Gross Bookings\" USING \"Booking Date\".\"Year\" =  VALUEOF(\"PREV_YEAR\") AND  \"Booking Date\".\"Sortable Number\" <= VALUEOF(\"PRV_YEAR_TD\") ) ) / FILTER(\"Fact - Bookings\".\"$ Total Gross Bookings\" USING \"Booking Date\".\"Year\" =  VALUEOF(\"PREV_YEAR\") AND \"Booking Date\".\"Sortable Number\" <= VALUEOF(\"PRV_YEAR_TD\") ) )";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\"[^\"]*\")\\.(\".*?\")").matcher(formulaData);

while (matcher.find()) 
{

 System.out.println(matcher.group(1)+ ": "+matcher.group(2));
 }
```

**Output:**

```
"Fact - Bookings": "$ Total Gross Bookings"
"Booking Date": "Year"
"Fact - Bookings": "$ Total Gross Bookings"
"Booking Date": "Year"
"Booking Date": "Sortable Number"
"Fact - Bookings": "$ Total Gross Bookings"
"Booking Date": "Year"
"Booking Date": "Sortable Number"
```

Comment: if you could explain your wonderful answer, it would be awesome @avinash raj

Comment: Hear the output I need is this: "Fact - Bookings": "$ Total Gross Bookings"
    "Booking Date": "Year"
    "Fact - Bookings": "$ Total Gross Bookings"
    "Booking Date": "Year"
     "Booking Date": "Sortable Number"
     "Fact - Bookings": "$ Total Gross Bookings"
    "Booking Date": "Year"
     "Booking Date": "Sortable Number"   The wrong output I am getting is "CUR_YEAR": "$ Total Gross Bookings" and "PRV_YEAR_TD": "$ Total Gross Bookings"